# Make a function execute before continuing

Tags: swift, asynchronous

Basically I have a function. And I have another function that has a completion handler. I want the result from the second function before continuing the lines of the first function. I tried Dispatch group but it doesn't work.

```
    func parseData(from json: [String: Any) -> Val {
      var a //some values I got from parsing that I NEED for B
      var anotherVariable
      B(a) { result in 
         anotherVariable = result
      }
      var otherVar = anotherVariable[0]
      return Val(a, anotherVariable, otherVar) // this is a struct                                               
      //returned
    }

    func B(_ a: a, completion: @escaping ([Res]) -> Void) {
      let group = DispatchGroup()
      var res = [Res]()

      SomeotherFunc(a, completion: { resp in
      res = resp
      group.leave()
    })
      group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(res)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please put a proper code to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that.

Please learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works and add another completion handler in `parseData`. And you are misusing `DispatchGroup` in `B`. As the name implies it's useful only for a *group* of asynchronous calls for example in a loop

```
func parseData(from json: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Val) -> Void) {
    var a //some values I got from parsing that I NEED for B
    var anotherVariable
    B(a) { result in
        anotherVariable = result
        completion(Val(a, anotherVariable, anotherVariable[0]))
    }
}

func B(_ a: a, completion: @escaping ([Res]) -> Void) {
    var res = [Res]()

    SomeotherFunc(a) { resp in
        res = resp
        completion(res)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah kinda a beginner, so I thought I could call an asynchronous in a synchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution. it is working**

```
func parseData(from json: [String: Any) -> Val {

        var a //some values I got from parsing that I NEED for B
        var anotherVariable

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()
        B(a) { result in
            anotherVariable = result
            group.leave()
        }

        group.wait()
        var otherVar = anotherVariable[0]
        return Val(a, anotherVariable, otherVar) // this is a struct
        //returned
    }

    func B(_ a: a, completion: @escaping ([Res]) -> Void) {
        SomeotherFunc(a, completion: { resp in
            completion(res)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't complete afterwards, like it just stays there

Comment: Have you any issue with the solution

Comment: Yeah, like it returns nothing. It builds, but it doesn't print and when I put the debugger in my code, it doesn't go inside anotherVariable = result before group.leave()

Comment: Can you put debug both point on `anotherVariable = result` and  `somefunc completion(res)`. Debug point first get the result from somefunction completion then comes to `antotherVariable = result`.

Comment: After the B function completion execute `group.leave` then finish `group.wait` and execute code.